# Finding duplicate div content and replacing it

Tags: jquery, duplicates

**Simply I want to:**

Create a size chart and add the available (enabled) sizes to replace those size div's in the size chart.

**To expand:**

I have all my shoe sizes from 4 to 12 hidden under a `div#hidden-shoe-sizes`

I then want to use `prependTo` to append the info from that `div` to the `.swatches-select` `div`

Then I want to replace the prepended content with the `.swatch-enabled` div's where there are duplicates. I'm using the `.basel-tooltip-label` `span` to find the duplicate items.

The reason I need to do this is to keep the `.swatches-select` div's that have `.swatch-enabled` to be unaffected as it has `data-value` with the div's that is used for my site.

I'm unsure where to start as I can't even get the parents of the duplicate div's to have a background. If I could do that maybe I can figure out the rest. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Please view my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sb1v47u/)

**CSS**

```
.basel-tooltip-label { display: none; }
.swatch-size-large { 
 padding: 10px 10px; 
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   float: left;
   margin-right:4px;
 }
 .swatch-size-large.swatch-enabled { 
   border-color: green; 
   background: green;
   color: white;
 }
 .blue { background: blue !important; }

 /* Hidden Sizes */
 #hidden-shoe-sizes { display: none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="swatches-select" data-id="pa_size">
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-enabled" data-value="6 ½" style="">
    <span class="basel-tooltip-label">6 ½</span>6 ½
  </div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-enabled" data-value="11" style="">
    <span class="basel-tooltip-label">11</span>11
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden-shoe-sizes">
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">4</span>4</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">5</span>5</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">5 ½</span>5 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">6</span>6</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">6 ½</span>6 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">7</span>7</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">7 ½</span>7 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">8</span>8</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">8 ½</span>8 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">9</span>9</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">10</span>10</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">11</span>11</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">12</span>12</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#hidden-shoe-sizes').contents().prependTo('.swatches-select');

if ($('.swatch-enabled span').text() == $('.swatch-disabled span').text()){
  $('span').parent().addClass('blue');
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply apply appropriate css style to the divs corresponding to available sizes?

Comment: Because as you see in the jsfiddle version: The green links have to replace the swatch-disabled links that match their basel-tooltip-label so I need to find a way to search for duplicate text() then I can properly solve it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a lot of messing around I came up with a working solution. My next question is how do I minify this as it's a lot of repeating jQuery code.

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gx1t058b/)

**Working jQuery Code:**

```js
$('#hidden-shoe-sizes').contents().prependTo('.swatches-select');


  var sizefour = $('[data-value="4"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizefour){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="4"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizefive = $('[data-value="5"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizefive){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="5"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizefivehalf = $('[data-value="5 ½"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizefivehalf){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="5 ½"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizesix = $('[data-value="6"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizesix){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="6"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizesixhalf = $('[data-value="6 ½"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizesixhalf){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="6 ½"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizeseven = $('[data-value="7"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizeseven){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="7"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizesevenhalf = $('[data-value="7 ½"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizesevenhalf){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="7 ½"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizeeight = $('[data-value="8"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizeeight){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="8"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizeeighthalf = $('[data-value="8 ½"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizeeighthalf){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="8 ½"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizenine = $('[data-value="9"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizenine){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="9"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizeten = $('[data-value="10"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizeten){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="10"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizeeleven = $('[data-value="11"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizeeleven){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="11"]'));
       };
    });
  var sizetwelve = $('[data-value="12"] span').text();
    $('.swatch-disabled .basel-tooltip-label').each(function(){
       if($(this).text()==sizetwelve){
           $(this).closest('.swatch-disabled').replaceWith($('[data-value="12"]'));
       };
    });
```

```css
.basel-tooltip-label { display: none; }
.swatch-size-large { 
  padding: 10px 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin-right:4px;
}
.swatch-size-large.swatch-enabled { 
  border-color: green; 
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
.blue { background: blue !important; }
.orange { background: orange !important; }

/* Hidden Sizes */
#hidden-shoe-sizes { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total">

<div class="swatches-select" data-id="pa_size">
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-enabled" data-value="6 ½" style="">
    <span class="basel-tooltip-label">6 ½</span>6 ½
  </div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-enabled" data-value="11" style="">
    <span class="basel-tooltip-label">11</span>11
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden-shoe-sizes">
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">4</span>4</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">5</span>5</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">5 ½</span>5 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">6</span>6</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">6 ½</span>6 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">7</span>7</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">7 ½</span>7 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">8</span>8</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">8 ½</span>8 ½</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">9</span>9</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">10</span>10</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">11</span>11</div>
  <div class="basel-swatch basel-tooltip  text-only swatch-size-large swatch-disabled"><span class="basel-tooltip-label">12</span>12</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to **minify** my code to not be so repetitive: [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893900/how-to-minify-my-repeating-text-equals-and-replacewith-code).